# Rounding in MS Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, rounding, worksheet-function

Whats the best way to round in VBA Access?

My current method utilizes the Excel method

```
Excel.WorksheetFunction.Round(...
```

But I am looking for a means that does not rely on Excel.

Comment: Depends on the version of Access. From Access 2000 on, a Round() function is included, but it doesn't give the results you might expect (see Lance Roberts' post below).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Be careful, the VBA Round function uses Banker's rounding, where it rounds .5 to an even number, like so:

```
Round (12.55, 1) would return 12.6 (rounds up) 
Round (12.65, 1) would return 12.6 (rounds down) 
Round (12.75, 1) would return 12.8 (rounds up)
```

Whereas the Excel Worksheet Function Round, always rounds .5 up.

I've done some tests and it looks like .5 up rounding (symmetric rounding) is also used by cell formatting, and also for Column Width rounding (when using the General Number format).  The 'Precision as displayed' flag doesn't appear to do any rounding itself, it just uses the rounded result of the cell format.

I tried to implement the SymArith function from Microsoft in VBA for my rounding, but found that Fix has an error when you try to give it a number like 58.55; the function giving a result of 58.5 instead of 58.6.  I then finally discovered that you can use the Excel Worksheet Round function, like so:

> **Application.Round(58.55, 1)**

This will allow you to do normal rounding in VBA, though it may not be as quick as some custom function.  I realize that this has come full circle from the question, but wanted to include it for completeness.

Answer (score 10):

To expand a little on the accepted answer:

"The Round function performs round to even, which is different from round to larger."
--Microsoft

Format always rounds up.

```
  Debug.Print Round(19.955, 2)
  'Answer: 19.95

  Debug.Print Format(19.955, "#.00")
  'Answer: 19.96
```

ACC2000: Rounding Errors When You Use Floating-Point Numbers: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210423

ACC2000: How to Round a Number Up or Down by a Desired Increment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209996

Round Function: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se6f2zfx.aspx

How To Implement Custom Rounding Procedures: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196652

Answer (score 4):

In Switzerland and in particulat in the insurance industry, we have to use several rounding rules, depending if it chash out, a benefit etc.

I currently use the function

```
Function roundit(value As Double, precision As Double) As Double
    roundit = Int(value / precision + 0.5) * precision
End Function
```

which seems to work fine

Comment: we don't use "banker's rounding"

Answer (score 2):

Int and Fix are both useful rounding functions, which give you the integer part of a number.

Int always rounds down - Int(3.5) = 3, Int(-3.5) = -4

Fix always rounds towards zero - Fix(3.5) = 3, Fix(-3.5) = -3

There's also the coercion functions, in particular CInt and CLng, which try to coerce a number to an integer type or a long type (integers are between -32,768 and 32,767, longs are between-2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647).  These will both round towards the nearest whole number, rounding away from zero from .5 - CInt(3.5) = 4, Cint(3.49) = 3, CInt(-3.5) = -4, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
1 place = INT(number x 10 + .5)/10
3 places = INT(number x 1000 + .5)/1000
```

and so on.You'll often find that apparently kludgy solutions like this are much faster than using Excel functions, because VBA seems to operate in a different memory space.

eg `If A > B Then MaxAB = A Else MaxAB = B` is about 40 x faster than using ExcelWorksheetFunction.Max

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the native functions of VBA that can perform rounding are either missing, limited, inaccurate, or buggy, and each addresses only a single rounding method. The upside is that they are fast, and that may in some situations be important.

However, often precision is mandatory, and with the speed of computers today, a little slower processing will hardly be noticed, indeed not for processing of single values. All the functions at the links below run at about 1 µs.

The complete set of functions - for all common rounding methods, all data types of VBA, for any value, and not returning unexpected values - can be found here:

[Rounding values up, down, by 4/5, or to significant figures (EE)](https://rdsrc.us/Mw1Iiy)

or here:

[Rounding values up, down, by 4/5, or to significant figures (CodePlex)](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1022704/Rounding-Values-Up-Down-By-Or-To-Significant-Figur)

Code only at GitHub:

[VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round.git)

They cover the normal rounding methods:

- Round down, with the option to round negative values towards zero
- Round up, with the option to round negative values away from zero
- Round by 4/5, either away from zero or to even  (Banker's Rounding)
- Round to a count of significant figures

The first three functions accept all the numeric data types, while the last exists in three varieties - for Currency, Decimal, and Double respectively.

They all accept a specified count of decimals - including a negative count which will round to tens, hundreds, etc. Those with Variant as return type will return Null for incomprehensible input

A test module for test and validating is included as well.

An example is here - for the common 4/5 rounding. Please study the in-line comments for the subtle details and the way *CDec* is used to avoid bit errors.

```
' Common constants.
'
Public Const Base10     As Double = 10

' Rounds Value by 4/5 with count of decimals as specified with parameter NumDigitsAfterDecimals.
'
' Rounds to integer if NumDigitsAfterDecimals is zero.
'
' Rounds correctly Value until max/min value limited by a Scaling of 10
' raised to the power of (the number of decimals).
'
' Uses CDec() for correcting bit errors of reals.
'
' Execution time is about 1µs.
'
Public Function RoundMid( _
    ByVal Value As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal NumDigitsAfterDecimals As Long, _
    Optional ByVal MidwayRoundingToEven As Boolean) _
    As Variant

    Dim Scaling     As Variant
    Dim Half        As Variant
    Dim ScaledValue As Variant
    Dim ReturnValue As Variant

    ' Only round if Value is numeric and ReturnValue can be different from zero.
    If Not IsNumeric(Value) Then
        ' Nothing to do.
        ReturnValue = Null
    ElseIf Value = 0 Then
        ' Nothing to round.
        ' Return Value as is.
        ReturnValue = Value
    Else
        Scaling = CDec(Base10 ^ NumDigitsAfterDecimals)

        If Scaling = 0 Then
            ' A very large value for Digits has minimized scaling.
            ' Return Value as is.
            ReturnValue = Value
        ElseIf MidwayRoundingToEven Then
            ' Banker's rounding.
            If Scaling = 1 Then
                ReturnValue = Round(Value)
            Else
                ' First try with conversion to Decimal to avoid bit errors for some reals like 32.675.
                ' Very large values for NumDigitsAfterDecimals can cause an out-of-range error 
                ' when dividing.
                On Error Resume Next
                ScaledValue = Round(CDec(Value) * Scaling)
                ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    ' Decimal overflow.
                    ' Round Value without conversion to Decimal.
                    ReturnValue = Round(Value * Scaling) / Scaling
                End If
            End If
        Else
            ' Standard 4/5 rounding.
            ' Very large values for NumDigitsAfterDecimals can cause an out-of-range error 
            ' when dividing.
            On Error Resume Next
            Half = CDec(0.5)
            If Value > 0 Then
                ScaledValue = Int(CDec(Value) * Scaling + Half)
            Else
                ScaledValue = -Int(-CDec(Value) * Scaling + Half)
            End If
            ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                ' Decimal overflow.
                ' Round Value without conversion to Decimal.
                Half = CDbl(0.5)
                If Value > 0 Then
                    ScaledValue = Int(Value * Scaling + Half)
                Else
                    ScaledValue = -Int(-Value * Scaling + Half)
                End If
                ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
            End If
        End If
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ' Rounding failed because values are near one of the boundaries of type Double.
            ' Return value as is.
            ReturnValue = Value
        End If
    End If

    RoundMid = ReturnValue

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about rounding to an integer value (and not rounding to *n* decimal places), there's always the old school way:

```
return int(var + 0.5)
```

(You can make this work for *n* decimal places too, but it starts to get a bit messy)

Answer (score 1):

Lance already mentioned the inherit rounding `bug` in VBA's implementation.
So I need a real rounding function in a VB6 app.
Here is one that I'm using.  It is based on one I found on the web as is indicated in the comments.

```
' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' RoundPenny
'
' Description:
'    rounds currency amount to nearest penny
'
' Arguments:
'    strCurrency        - string representation of currency value
'
' Dependencies:
'
' Notes:
' based on RoundNear found here:
' http://advisor.com/doc/08884
'
' History:
' 04/14/2005 - WSR : created
'
Function RoundPenny(ByVal strCurrency As String) As Currency

         Dim mnyDollars    As Variant
         Dim decCents      As Variant
         Dim decRight      As Variant
         Dim lngDecPos     As Long

1        On Error GoTo RoundPenny_Error

         ' find decimal point
2        lngDecPos = InStr(1, strCurrency, ".")

         ' if there is a decimal point
3        If lngDecPos > 0 Then

            ' take everything before decimal as dollars
4           mnyDollars = CCur(Mid(strCurrency, 1, lngDecPos - 1))

            ' get amount after decimal point and multiply by 100 so cents is before decimal point
5           decRight = CDec(CDec(Mid(strCurrency, lngDecPos)) / 0.01)

            ' get cents by getting integer portion
6           decCents = Int(decRight)

            ' get leftover
7           decRight = CDec(decRight - decCents)

            ' if leftover is equal to or above round threshold
8           If decRight >= 0.5 Then

9              RoundPenny = mnyDollars + ((decCents + 1) * 0.01)

            ' if leftover is less than round threshold
10          Else

11             RoundPenny = mnyDollars + (decCents * 0.01)

12          End If

         ' if there is no decimal point
13       Else

            ' return it
14          RoundPenny = CCur(strCurrency)

15       End If

16       Exit Function

RoundPenny_Error:

17       Select Case Err.Number

            Case 6

18             Err.Raise vbObjectError + 334, c_strComponent & ".RoundPenny", "Number '" & strCurrency & "' is too big to represent as a currency value."

19          Case Else

20             DisplayError c_strComponent, "RoundPenny"

21       End Select

End Function
' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
VBA.Round(1.23342, 2) // will return 1.23
```

Comment: That might not get you what you expect... that round function uses bankers rounding vs. what most of us are taught in elementary school.

Comment: It works for my requirements, but thanks for the note. I'll take that into considerations before I use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is easy way to always round up to next whole number in Access 2003:

```
BillWt = IIf([Weight]-Int([Weight])=0,[Weight],Int([Weight])+1)
```

For example:

- [Weight] = 5.33 ; Int([Weight]) = 5 ; so 5.33-5 = 0.33 (<>0), so answer is BillWt = 5+1 = 6.
- [Weight] = 6.000, Int([Weight]) = 6 , so 6.000-6 = 0, so answer is BillWt = 6.

Comment: THE easy way to _round up_ is: `BillWt = -Int(-[Weight])`.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of penny splits not adding up to the amount that they were originally split from, I created a user defined function.

```
Function PennySplitR(amount As Double, Optional splitRange As Variant, Optional index As Integer = 0, Optional n As Integer = 0, Optional flip As Boolean = False) As Double
' This Excel function takes either a range or an index to calculate how to "evenly" split up dollar amounts
' when each split amount must be in pennies.  The amounts might vary by a penny but the total of all the
' splits will add up to the input amount.

' Splits a dollar amount up either over a range or by index
' Example for passing a range: set range $I$18:$K$21 to =PennySplitR($E$15,$I$18:$K$21) where $E$15 is the amount and $I$18:$K$21 is the range
'                              it is intended that the element calling this function will be in the range
' or to use an index and total items instead of a range: =PennySplitR($E$15,,index,N)
' The flip argument is to swap rows and columns in calculating the index for the element in the range.

' Thanks to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559279/excel-cell-from-which-a-function-is-called for the application.caller.row hint.
Dim evenSplit As Double, spCols As Integer, spRows As Integer
If (index = 0 Or n = 0) Then
    spRows = splitRange.Rows.count
    spCols = splitRange.Columns.count
    n = spCols * spRows
    If (flip = False) Then
       index = (Application.Caller.Row - splitRange.Cells.Row) * spCols + Application.Caller.Column - splitRange.Cells.Column + 1
     Else
       index = (Application.Caller.Column - splitRange.Cells.Column) * spRows + Application.Caller.Row - splitRange.Cells.Row + 1
    End If
 End If
 If (n < 1) Then
    PennySplitR = 0
    Return
 Else
    evenSplit = amount / n
    If (index = 1) Then
            PennySplitR = Round(evenSplit, 2)
        Else
            PennySplitR = Round(evenSplit * index, 2) - Round(evenSplit * (index - 1), 2)
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following **simple** function to round my **currencies** as in our company we **always** round up.

```
Function RoundUp(Number As Variant)
   RoundUp = Int(-100 * Number) / -100
   If Round(Number, 2) = Number Then RoundUp = Number
End Function
```

but this will ALWAYS round up to 2 decimals and may also error.

even if it is negative it will round up  (-1.011 will be -1.01   and   1.011 will be 1.02)

so to provide more options for *rounding up* (or down for negative) you **could** use this function:

```
Function RoundUp(Number As Variant, Optional RoundDownIfNegative As Boolean = False)
On Error GoTo err
If Number = 0 Then
err:
    RoundUp = 0
ElseIf RoundDownIfNegative And Number < 0 Then
    RoundUp = -1 * Int(-100 * (-1 * Number)) / -100
Else
    RoundUp = Int(-100 * Number) / -100
End If
If Round(Number, 2) = Number Then RoundUp = Number
End Function
```

(used in a module, if it isn't obvious)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function RoundUpDown(value, decimals, updown)
If IsNumeric(value) Then
        rValue = Round(value, decimals)
        rDec = 10 ^ (-(decimals))
        rDif = rValue - value
        If updown = "down" Then 'rounding for "down" explicitly.
            If rDif > 0 Then ' if the difference is more than 0, it rounded up.
                RoundUpDown = rValue - rDec
            ElseIf rDif < 0 Then ' if the difference is less than 0, it rounded down.
                RoundUpDown = rValue
            Else
                RoundUpDown = rValue
            End If
        Else 'rounding for anything thats not "down"
            If rDif > 0 Then ' if the difference is more than 0, it rounded up.
                RoundUpDown = rValue
            ElseIf rDif < 0 Then ' if the difference is less than 0, it rounded down.
                RoundUpDown = rValue + rDec
            Else
                RoundUpDown = rValue
            End If
        End If

End If
'RoundUpDown(value, decimals, updown) 'where updown is "down" if down. else rounds up. put this in your program.
End Function
```