# I am trying to add a new column in Access called Reduced Price that reduces the ProductUnitPrice column by 10%

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductDescription, ProductUnitsOnHand, ProductUnitPrice
FROM tblProduct
ALTER tblProduct 
ADD COLUMN Reduced Price NUMBER DEFAULT 0
```

This is what I have been able to figure out so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to add a permanent column to an existing table, or just output an additional column with your results?  I'm going to guess the latter.  If I'm right, then try this:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductDescription, ProductUnitsOnHand,
       ProductUnitPrice, (ProductUnitPrice * .9) as [Reduced Price]
FROM tblProduct
```

Comment: You are correct thanks a lot. Also, how can I make only display 2 decimal places?

Comment: Using this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441600/write-a-number-with-two-decimal-places-sql-server  `SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(ProductUnitPrice * .9)) as [Reduced Price]`

Comment: Convert decimal will not work in MS Access see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630905/rounding-in-access/11630940#11630940 instead