# How to set a runtime datatype in MS Access using Design mode

Tags: ms-access

I've been working on MS Access.  My students have to create a runtime field but I can't for the life of me determine how to set the datatype without going into the SQL itself.  Is it possible to use the design view to set this up something like

```
Somefrigginfield (Set data type here e.g. Currency) (Decimal places to round here) : [Somefieldname] *1.10
```

I know in SQL it would be something akin to

```
Select ID as int expr1
```

It's been a while but you get the idea

(FYI if this is in the wrong forumn of stack please let me know where to shoot it)

Comment: what do you mean by runtime field? you have a textbox and you would like to change the format? tb.format = currency? or are you trying to declare a decimal variable? dim xyz as double?

Comment: When designing queries in MS Access there is a design mode feature.  I would like to continue to use this to make it easy for students so I'm wondering if there is a way to do a runtime field in this way with parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the query in design mode:
in the design view fields just type

```
CalcValue : [Fieldname] * 1.0
```

in SQL it would look like : `SELECT ([FieldName] * 1.10) as CalcValue`

or:

```
calcValue : Format([property_Rent],"Currency")
```

OR:

[image]

Comment: If you read my comments I know this.  What I'm asking for is to be able to set the data type and rounding in the design view.

Comment: @Kevrone: ahh okay.. just open the property sheet view for the query and click the fields you want to format and set the formats:

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you mean:

```
SELECT aTable.aNumber, 
       CCur([aInteger])/3 AS [Currency], 
       Round(CCur([aInteger])/3,2) AS Round, 
       Format(CCur([aInteger])/3,"Currency") AS Format
FROM aTable;
```

In design view

[image: query design]

Giving the results below, you will note that null fields / columns give an error. The Nz function is probably the easiest way to avoid this.

[image]

See also: [Rounding in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630905/rounding-in-access/11630940#11630940)

Comment: Awesome explanation of putting the programming in.  I was looking for the simpler solution provided with the parameters function as it's for students but this is awesome for me to be able to go straight in.