# Round second decimal up regardless of third decimal

Tags: ms-access

I'm using Access 2010  to append a calculated field into a table [payroll]. The way Access rounds will make a number even but I need access to round the number up regardless of the third decimal spot if there is one (excluding 0 of course) so 20.100 can stay as 20.10 but 20.101 should round up to 20.11.

Examples:
958.165 im getting 958.16 should be 958.17

963.915 im getting 963.92 is correct as  963.92

1232.205 im getting 1232.2 should be 1232.21

1224.235 im getting  1224.23 should be 1224.24

Comment: Are you using `ROUND` or `ROUNDUP`

Comment: @rajmore, I do not believe ROUNDUP exists in MS Access. To the OP, you might like to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137114/how-to-round-in-ms-access-vba/266745#266745, format will give a round up for 5 or greater, rounding up for numbers below that gets more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Round function and add 0.009 to the variable before doing the rounding.

For example:

```
Dim dblValue As Double
dblValue= 1224.235
dblValue=Round(dblValue + 0.009,2)
```