# Miscalculating sum(table.field) in form txtbox

Tags: ms-access

I have a table `tblTimeInLieu` with a field `HoursTaken` containing these values: 1; 0.5; 2.25; 0.66

I then have a form `frmTimeInLieu`, Record Source: TimeInLieu, which contains a text box `txtHoursUsed`, Control Source: `Sum([HoursTaken])` which returns this value: 4.41000003.

...

HOW!?

I've band-aided it by replacing the control source with `FormatNumber(Sum([HoursTaken]), 2)` so that it looks right for now, but I can't for the life of me work out what's going on.

---

Potential relevant information:

- It changed when I added the last value. Before then it was fine, always giving no more than 2 digits after the decimal point.
- The `HoursTaken` field contains data of type `single` with "Decimal Places" set to "Auto."
- I've added a Data Macro on the Before Change event of the Table that looks like this, but that's changed nothing. It was a bit of a long shot:

  ```
  SetField
      Name HoursTaken
      Value = FormatNumber([HoursTaken], 2)
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Floating point number inaccuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/7296893)!

Since your column is a *Single*, which is the smallest floating number data type Access has, most operations that involves this column multiple times are bound to produce inaccurate results.

Either change your column type to *Decimal*, *Currency*, or use a rounding function to discard rounding data.

If you would change your column to a *Double*, the result would still be inaccurate, but with a smaller error.

Comment: Ok, so I'm planning to store it as a decimal *but* - is there a rounding function that avoids bankers rounding in Access, or would I have to make my own?

Comment: Also, could I eliminate the need for that data macro simply by setting the field to a decimal with scale set at 2?

Comment: `Format` in a data macro of course changes the data stored. For rounding functions, I tend to refer to [this page](http://allenbrowne.com/round.html) by Allen Browne, you might use the tricks described there, but you might also want to write your own. You can also view [this Q&A here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/137114/7296893), many good answers and prewritten rounding functions.

Comment: Oh, and if you want to avoid additional floating-point errors when rounding, [Gustav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36966140/7296893) on that Q&A I linked to works with the decimal type to avoid that. Older answers tend to use doubles, because decimal is a relatively new type and more computationally intensive.